# Return in previous value if the value not exist in textbox values from database

Tags: php, jquery

Okay, the main problem in here is I need to compare the value get from database through ajax. The values of textbox is from database depending on its option value.

I saw this script but I can't figure out how I can mix it to my autocomplete code. The source is the one of my big problem.

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#auto").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(src, request.term)
                , el = this.element[0];

            if (results.length) {
                el.value = results[0];
                el.setSelectionRange(request.term.length, el.value.length);
            }

            response(results);
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
            if (!ui.item) {
                this.value = '';
            }
        }
    });
});
    </script>
```

I want to return the textbox empty if the current value is not on the list.

**My page**

```
<script>
function changeAutoComplete (val) {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'autocomplete.php?selected='+val
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 Drop1
 <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015");
    $combo = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM category GROUP BY cat_code ORDER BY id");
    $option = '';
     while($row = $combo->fetch_assoc())
        {
        $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['cat_code'].'">'.$row['category'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
<select id="main" name="main" onchange="changeAutoComplete(this.value)">
<option value=""  selected="selected">Choose</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>

<div class="demo-frame">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags" name="items">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get it from server. then you have to use remote example of auto-complete.

For that you have to use anonymous function function( request, response ) for your source.

Here is auto-complete remote example on below link

```
  http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote
```

Update your source attribute as follow according to your need

```
source: function( request, response ) {
   $.getJSON( "search.php", {
      term: extractLast( request.term )
   }, response );
}
```